# ReactJS - Get two divs two follow each others scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have two divs one is master and the other one is slave, I would like slave and master to follow each others scrolling.

master will always have the same width and height but slave can have any width and any height.

Problem: when I start scrolling it triggers an infinite loop because I'm using two useEffects to look at each others scroll percentage and update scrolling accordingly.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-feather-3teev?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I do understand that the problem is that when slave changes then is updates master and when master changes that updates slave and this is causing an infinite loop, but how do I work around this ?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, using useEffect hooks was a mistake, because when one position changes the other will as well and this caused an infinite loop. I simply used the onScroll prop and selected the parent node and then the other div within the parent and modified the scroll position that way.

Easiest way to understand is to look at the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-js-scroll-sync-ee9wb

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the sandbox, it was a great help, though you can improve the logic, because currently, both the scrolls are trying to scroll each other every time. and it's kind of going in a loop and that's why there's lag. You can improve that using conditional logic in each scroll listener.